# Parental controls floods system.log with errors

Tags: macos, parental-controls

I was digging around for fun, and I found that the `system.log` was ***FLOODED*** with errors. Here's an example.

```
Mar 20 08:46:34 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[696]: -[ActivityTracker contentFilterPageWasVisited:address:] [1382:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 UserInfo=0x1378f0 "An error occurred while saving."
Mar 20 08:46:34 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[696]: -[ActivityTracker contentFilterPageWasVisited:address:] [1382:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 UserInfo=0x137c00 "An error occurred while saving."
Mar 20 08:46:35 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[696]: -[ActivityTracker contentFilterPageWasVisited:address:] [1382:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 UserInfo=0x41ed90 "An error occurred while saving."
Mar 20 08:46:35 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[696]: -[ActivityTracker contentFilterPageWasVisited:address:] [1382:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 UserInfo=0x43d250 "An error occurred while saving."
Mar 20 08:46:35 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[696]: -[ActivityTracker contentFilterPageWasVisited:address:] [1382:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 UserInfo=0x43d2a0 "An error occurred while saving."
Mar 20 08:46:35 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[696]: -[ActivityTracker contentFilterPageWasVisited:address:] [1382:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 UserInfo=0x4369f0 "An error occurred while saving."
Mar 20 08:46:35 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[696]: -[ActivityTracker contentFilterPageWasVisited:address:] [1382:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 UserInfo=0x453890 "An error occurred while saving."
Mar 20 08:46:40 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[696]: -[ActivityTracker contentFilterPageWasVisited:address:] [1382:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 UserInfo=0x452360 "An error occurred while saving."
Mar 20 08:46:40 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[696]: -[ActivityTracker contentFilterPageWasVisited:address:] [1382:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 UserInfo=0x137f10 "An error occurred while saving."
Mar 20 08:46:40 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[696]: -[ActivityTracker contentFilterPageWasVisited:address:] [1382:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 UserInfo=0x452530 "An error occurred while saving."
Mar 20 08:46:40 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[696]: -[ActivityTracker contentFilterPageWasVisited:address:] [1382:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 UserInfo=0x137cb0 "An error occurred while saving."
Mar 20 08:46:40 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[696]: -[ActivityTracker contentFilterPageWasVisited:address:] [1382:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 UserInfo=0x1380c0 "An error occurred while saving."
Mar 20 08:46:41 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[696]: -[ActivityTracker contentFilterPageWasVisited:address:] [1382:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 UserInfo=0x138510 "An error occurred while saving."
Mar 20 08:46:50 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[696]: -[ActivityTracker contentFilterPageWasVisited:address:] [1382:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 UserInfo=0x138710 "An error occurred while saving."
Mar 20 08:46:50 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[696]: -[ActivityTracker contentFilterPageWasVisited:address:] [1382:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 UserInfo=0x456ed0 "An error occurred while saving."
Mar 20 08:47:10 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[696]: -[ActivityTracker contentFilterPageWasVisited:address:] [1382:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 UserInfo=0x4570d0 "An error occurred while saving."
```

How big would an average `system.log` file be, and would it get "cleaned out" periodically by monthly processes or something like that? Here is my `ls -l | grep system.log`.

```
-rw-r-----    1 root   admin  11419271 Mar 20 09:05 system.log
-rw-r-----    1 root   admin    275257 Mar 12 00:30 system.log.0.bz2
-rw-r-----    1 root   admin     70129 Mar  4 00:30 system.log.1.bz2
-rw-r-----    1 root   admin     15149 Mar  2 00:10 system.log.2.bz2
-rw-r-----    1 root   admin     20181 Mar  1 00:30 system.log.3.bz2
-rw-r-----    1 root   admin     36629 Feb 29 00:30 system.log.4.bz2
-rw-r-----    1 root   admin   1608620 Feb 28 00:30 system.log.5.bz2
-rw-r-----    1 root   admin      9129 Jan  8 00:30 system.log.6.bz2
-rw-r-----    1 root   admin     59804 Jan  7 00:30 system.log.7.bz2
```

I have had my computer for just about 2 years. If there is a problem, I would appreciate your thoughts and help.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can find the Parental Controls activity log file. Make sure it's not on a full volume, make sure it's not corrupt (try moving it aside or deleting it and letting the system recreate it), and make sure it has the right permissions (perhaps run a "Repair Permissions" on that volume from Disk Utility)

See the following answer for more information about these files.
[How can I view Mac OS X Parental Control files with format .data?](https://superuser.com/questions/297852/how-can-i-view-mac-os-x-parental-control-files-with-format-data)

The more I read through that other question and answer, the more convinced I am that one or more of your parental controls log files (which are actually CoreData .data files, not plain text logs) are corrupt.

Comment: I deleted it, and I now have to see if those errors show up.

Comment: Still do... This current `system.log` has been used for 8 days and is 12.1 MB.

Comment: What exactly did you delete? The binary plist files in `.../[username]/[year]/[month]/...`, or the actual SQLite data file `.../[username]/events.data` ? If you didn't get them all, just move aside the entire ParentalControls folder and see if it gets recreated and the errors stop.

Comment: :D I'll try deleting the username folder...

Comment: Nope didn't work. It still gives those errors.